# Python binary string representation

Tags: python, string, encoding

can anyone please help me with following issue:

I have a str1 defined locally as `str1 = 'CV\xca\x86\x11\x85\x01\xc8'` and str2 received from another layer of code:

`print str2 gives 'CV\xca\x86\x11\x85\x01\xc8'`
so they look identical, however:

`print binascii.hexlify(str1) gives 4356ca86118501c8 or INT: 4852288325706645960`

but for str2

`print binascii.hexlify(str2) gives 43565c7863615c7838365c7831315c7838355c7830315c786338
or int 108206947078930905153039906183652663420044626270557263434900280`

The problem seems to be probably different encoding where

`print chardet.detect(str1) gives me my local encoding: {'confidence': 0.73, 'language': '', 'encoding': 'Windows-1252'}`

`print chardet.detect(str2) gives {'confidence': 1, 'language': '', 'encoding': 'ascii'}`

How can I modify the str2 to get the same hex or int values from it like for str1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string with literal backslashes, `'x'` characters and hex digits:

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> unhexlify('43565c7863615c7838365c7831315c7838355c7830315c786338')
'CV\\xca\\x86\\x11\\x85\\x01\\xc8'
```

The representation of the string doubles the backslashes, so you can reproduce the value. The representation of the other string has no such doubling, because the `\xhh` sequences each form a single character:

```
>>> unhexlify('4356ca86118501c8')
'CV\xca\x86\x11\x85\x01\xc8'
```

Compare the individual characters:

```
>>> 'CV\xca\x86\x11\x85\x01\xc8'[2]
'\xca'
>>> 'CV\\xca\\x86\\x11\\x85\\x01\\xc8'[2]
'\\'
```

You can decode escape sequences with the `string_escape` codec:

```
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> 'CV\\xca\\x86\\x11\\x85\\x01\\xc8'.decode('string_escape')
'CV\xca\x86\x11\x85\x01\xc8'
>>> hexlify('CV\\xca\\x86\\x11\\x85\\x01\\xc8'.decode('string_escape'))
'4356ca86118501c8'
```